# Money regex template

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need a money template like:

```
999 999 999,5
999 999 999 
20 500,8
20 500
```

I've used https://regex101.com/ and create `^\d{1,3}( \d{3})+(,?\d{1})?$`. I thought it's right because my sting was matched, but when I try to implement it

```
var str = "20 000,5"
console.log(str.match("^\d{1,3}( \d{3})+(,?\d{1})?$"));
```

I have `null`.

What I have done wrong?

Comment: Escape the \ characters, or use regex notation: `console.log(str.match(/^\d{1,3}( \d{3})+(,?\d{1})?$/));`

Comment: `^\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*(?:,\d)?$` is slightly shorter. Not sure if you meant to ensure that the second group is always there, but I changed `+` to `*`. I also changed grouping to non-capture groups. Also `{1}` is redundant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape backslash.

```
str.match("^\\d{1,3}( \\d{3})+(,?\\d{1})?$");
```

**Edit**: Change regex pattern so that it could match numbers below `1 000`.

I have also removed `?` on `,` because it seems strange?

```
str.match("^\\d{1,3}( \\d{3})*(,\\d)?$");
```

Comment: I'd also change it so it works with numbers below `1 000` : `(\d{1,3})*(\s\d{3})+(\,?\d{1,2})?`

Comment: @Alfabravo that may not be the intended use, but your regex doesn't solve this. Try your regex on `500,5`. If you want below `1 000`, you need to change `+` to `*`

Comment: @pciang either keep your existing regex or use the one I posted in comments below the question as `^\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*(?:,\d)?$`

Comment: i have also removed `?` on `,` cos it seems strange... i think the OP was trying to match `,` or space?

Comment: @pciang I think it was intended to be a *match 0 or 1 `,`* for decimal places. I think that was incorrect, which, is why I removed it in the regex above

Comment: @pciang, I need to match also decimal with `,`